# Xcode 8: UICollectionView unexpected space

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, xcode8

Trying to make a UICollectonView, but when i drag it, there's unexpected space above the actual view and it takes space

Screenshot, above the red line is the space

[image: Screenshot 18]

Comment: Share your storyboard snapshot with uicollection view constraint setup and uicollection view cell configuration.

Comment: its a new one with the default configuration just practicing

Comment: Default may not add any space. In my answer I have added collection view with default configuration and it has no such kind of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For your collection view set its frame or autolayout constraints.**

[image]

**For your collection view cell, try following:**

This is because of either `minimumSpacing` between line and/or cells or `sectionInset` with respect to cell size..

Try to change/update values for:

- Section Inset (Top and/or Bottom)
- Header (Height)
- Cell Size (Height)
- Min Space (for lines)

You see changes in space you've in your snapshot.

Look at this snapshot:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, but i didn't work and i already tried this

Answer (score 0):

In the attributes inspector of the `ViewController` in Xcode, unselect the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` option like in the screenshot below.

[image]